# Logging exceptions with Hellang ProblemDetails

Tags: exception, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm using Hellang ProblemDetails package in a Web API application using .Net Core 5 and I need to log the exception before sending response back to client.

I tried using ExceptionHandler middleware and Hellang ProblemDetails Middleware together, but they didn't work together. How can I log exception globally while using Hellang ProblemDetails?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some reading, I realized I could't use ExceptionHandler middleware and Hellang ProblemDetails together because both change the response in their own way and affect one another.

Based on the documentation [here](https://github.com/khellang/Middleware/blob/master/src/ProblemDetails/ProblemDetailsMiddleware.cs) you can use one of the configuration options of the ProblemDetails package to excute code before changing response and there you can log all the information you need.

```
services.AddProblemDetails(options =>
        {
            options.IncludeExceptionDetails = (context, ex) =>
            {
                var environment = context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IWebHostEnvironment>();
                return environment.IsDevelopment();
            };

            options.Map<IdentityException>(exception => new ProblemDetails()
            {
                Title = exception.Title,
                Detail = exception.Detail,
                Status = StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError,
                Type = exception.Type,
                Instance = exception.ToString()
            });

            options.OnBeforeWriteDetails = (ctx, pr) =>
            {
                //here you can do the logging
                logger.LogError("Exception Occurred!!!!");
                logger.LogError(pr.Detail);
                logger.LogError(pr.Instance);
            };
        });
```

Here, I use a custom exception with extra fields that are needed for problem details object in response, and I use the Instance field to hold the exception and log all the information I need before returning response back to client.

Comment: Thank you for sharing the solution with code example!

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to configure `options.ShouldLogUnhandledException` to cover your cases

https://github.com/khellang/Middleware/blob/5d5257ef54d82c902dbf087486365032d4804aac/src/ProblemDetails/ProblemDetailsMiddleware.cs#L119

Example:

`options.ShouldLogUnhandledException = (_, ex, d) => d.Status is null or >= 500 || ex is ValidationException;`